# Include many to one records in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, include

I need to include **CasePriority** into **CaseType**. Is it possible to do?

I do this but no joy...

```
this.ObjectContext.CaseType.Include("CaseTypePriority").Include("CaseTypePriority.CasePriority");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah!!! I found solution :)

```
 var r = this.ObjectContext.CaseTypePriority.Include("CaseType").Include("CasePriority").ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using lambdas to strongly type your 'include's... Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232) for how it's done in EF, which should work fine for you. basically inside the Include you will Select() the grandchild elements (CasePriority).